# React native Expo i have error when i try to remove image

Tags: react-native, expo

am trying to build React native app with  Expo i have error when i try to remove image  : onRemoveImage is not function can someone help with this code this is my first time building app

[image]

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from "react-native";
import ImageInput from "./ImageInput";

function ImageInputList({ imageUris = [], onRemoveImage, onAddImage }) {
  const scrollView = useRef();


  return (
    <View>
      <ScrollView
        ref={scrollView}
        horizontal
        onContentSizeChange={() => scrollView.current.scrollToEnd()}
      >
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {imageUris.map((uri) => (
            <View key={uri} style={styles.image}>
              <ImageInput
                imageUri={uri}
                onChangeImage= {()=> onRemoveImage(uri)}
              />
            </View>
          ))}
          <ImageInput onChangeImage={(uri) => onAddImage(uri)} />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: "row",
  },
  image: {
    marginRight: 10,
  },
});

export default ImageInputList;
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code  `onChangeImage= {()=> onRemoveImage(uri)}` you use onRemoveImage as a function but it isn't cause you use onRemoveImage as a `parameter ( value )` for the main `function ImageInputList`

Comment: thank you for your respond . what i can change to make code work

Comment: I suggest you to not modify something on it but  check .the parent component that call the function ImageInputList , because i thinks this want to pass a function in the props , check something like this : 

<ImageInputList imageUris={} onRemoveImage={this.onRemoveImage}  onAddImage={this.onAddImage }/> 

 and check if onRemoveImage and onAddImage is well declared